# Production release of NHibernate

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, orm

I am trying to get started working with NHibernate. I went to download the latest production release at https://www.hibernate.org/6.html. The NHibernate download says development beside it, whereas other downloads say Production.

Is this what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link there actually takes you to a page on SourceForge (http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhibernate/files/) that lists all of the .NET downloads, not just the one shown.  From there you can find all available releases. The current release at time of writing is the 2.1.0.GA release.

(Not sure why the main Hibernate page is saying 2.0.0 beta - that's not very helpful...)

Answer (score 2):

NHibernate is no longer on www.hibernate.org, there is just old stuff around.

Take a look at [www.nhforge.org](http://www.nhforge.org). The currently actual version is 2.1.